# Swift - Unable to Show Detail View with Naivgation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am running into a very strange issue here when it comes to segues between table view controller and details view.

It works with one implementation, but when I followed the same steps (& code) it doesn't work somewhere else.

Basically I have a table populated from Parse backend and once a row is clicked it would show the details for that record. For Orders View Controller, when the row is selected, it shows the detail view with a navigation in top (inherited) and a back button to the list. In the Friends Controller, when I click on a friend row, it shows the details view with details of a friend correctly. But no navigation top bar and no back button.

I also noticed the animation in the Orders scenario is different (left slide) where as in the Friends scenario (not working) it is more of coming from bottom to top.

Below are details to help assess the problem further and am glad to offer more upon request since I am not sure what part is relevant or not.

[image: This is the order scenario. The segue is of type Show Details]

Now for the Friends scenario:

[image: This is the friends scenario. The segue type is again Show Details]

To illustrate the flow of the order, it goes like this:
[image: The back button is showing]

[image: Back button and nav bar is not showing.]

I tried doing this but it didn't work:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is segue between Friend view and Detail Friend view. Go storyboard and choose segue between them same config with image below:
[image]

Hope this help!

Answer (score -1):

Try redoing the segue. Just Ctrl-drag from the prototype cell to the detail view controller. Make sure that you make a segue of type `show`.